# Changing a filename by incrementing

Tags: c++, for-loop

So I have this for loop:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 13; x++)
{
    inputImages.push_back(Image(3264, 2448));
    inputImages[x] = readPPM("Images/ImageStacker_set1/IMG_1.ppm");
}
```

What i'm trying to do is to add the loop variable to the filename so it will  increment the filename where it says:

```
IMG_1.ppm
```

To replace the 1 with the variable x so each time it loops it will add a new file to the array.

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
inputImages[x] = readPPM("Images/ImageStacker_set1/IMG_"<< x <<".ppm");
```

Does anyone have a method for doing this?

Comment: use `+` instead of `<<`

Comment: Like inputImages[x] = readPPM("Images/ImageStacker_set1/IMG_" + x +".ppm"); ?

Comment: That will error @Fureeish you need to use `to_string` look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very quick way to solve this:

```
inputImages[x] = readPPM(string("Images/ImageStacker_set1/IMG_" + to_string( x ) + ".ppm").c_str());
```

Comment: When I do it like this inputImages[x] = readPPM("Images/ImageStacker_set1/IMG_" + std::to_string( x ) + ".ppm"); I get the error: no suitable conversion function from "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>" to "const char *"

Comment: New error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type ?

Comment: @newbie123 this should work I did not realize your method took a `const char *` till now.

Comment: You don't need to copy the final result of the concatenation to yet another temp `std::string`, as it is already a `std::string` due to one of the concatenations using `std::to_string()`. You can replace `string(` with just `(`, eg: `readPPM(("Images/ImageStacker_set1/IMG_" + to_string(x) + ".ppm").c_str());`